# How can I use a RPi interfacing with a Python program to count PWM pulses in the 0-40 khz range?

Tags: gpio, python

How can I use a RPi interfaced with a Python program to count PWM pulses in the 0-40 khz range?  The Pi would not be generating the pulses. I don't see any similar questions. I am a total newbee to RPi and Python so I need general directions to explore and I'll do my own research from there.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to count pulses. PWM usually produces a constant frequency so the number of pulses is predictable.

Answer (score 1):

For Pi models earlier than the Pi5 have a look at [pigpio](https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/).

A good start point is this Python [PWM monitor](https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_read_PWM_py).